# More elegant way to add button to array

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I am making a small tic tac toe game with a `Button Array` and was I was creating the Array, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to assign them the array. 
My current code is:

```
MovementPiece[0, 0] = button1;
MovementPiece[0, 1] = button2;
MovementPiece[0, 2] = button3;
MovementPiece[1, 0] = button4;
MovementPiece[1, 1] = button5;
MovementPiece[1, 2] = button6;
MovementPiece[2, 0] = button7;
MovementPiece[2, 1] = button8;
MovementPiece[2, 2] = button9;
```

My problem now is that my program cannot see the buttons because they are declared locally.

```
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button[,] MovementPiece = { { button1, button2, button3 }, 
                                  { button4, button5, button6 },
                                  { button7, button8, button9 } };
        //Initiates the button array.

        for (int Row = 0; Row <= 2; Row++)
        {
            for (int Column = 0; Column <= 2; Column++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(MovementPiece[Row, Column]);
                //Sets the handler for the buttons.
                MovementPiece[Row, Column].Click += new EventHandler(MovementPiece_Click);
            }
        }

 Public void Clear()
 {
 //Can not see buttons.
 }
```

Thank you, I am a beginning so take it easy :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment you need to declare your array at the class level and initialize it in your Form_Load Event Handler that way it will be visible to your entire form. Something like this should work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[,] MovementPiece;  //Declare at the class level
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovementPiece = new Button[,]{ { button1, button2, button3 }, 
                          { button4, button5, button6 },
                          { button7, button8, button9 }
                        }; //Initialized in your Form Load event

        // Do your button initialization here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I was so close. I forgot a simple little step. To initialize the `Button`! My bad, thank you though!!

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you can use array initializers like this:

```
Button[,] MovementPiece = { { button1, button2, button3 }, 
                              { button4, button5, button6 },
                              { button7, button8, button9 }
                            };
```

**Further reading**

- [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [C# Specification 12.6 Array initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Though this works, I now have the problem that my `Buttons` are global therefore the rest of my program can't use them. I have this on my form_load and it must be there because the buttons are Initialized there... Updated problem ^

Comment: @Rynoh97 Declare MovementPiece as a class level variable, initialize it in your Form Load eventhandler

Comment: @MarkHall How would I go about that?

Comment: if you have a different question ask a new question, don't completely change it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array like this, move all your buttons into a panel. (it's a control) You can then loop through the panel's "Controls" list.

```
foreach(Button button IN mypanel.Controls){
    //do stuff
}
```

Much easier to work with.